# Getting 502 Bad Gateway error when executing Postman curl request locally

Tags: nginx, proxy, postman, bad-gateway, http-status-code-502

I am getting a 502 Bad Gateway error coming from nginx after I execute the same curl command that is working from Postman. I try to connect to the Ciena lab but I am not being able to do that. I am working behind a proxy and I tried to execute the curl with and without it but is not working neither.

How could I avoid receiving this 502 Bad Gateway? Thank you in advance :)